# Assembly.GetType is returning null

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to dynamically load an encryption assembly but my `GetType` is returning null, even though I am using the correct class name.  Here's the code:

```
//Load encryption assembly.
Assembly encryptionAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Encryption.dll");
foreach(Type t in encryptionAssembly.GetTypes())
   {
      MessageBox.Show(t.Name.ToString());
      // This shows "Encryption"
   }
Type encryptionClass = encryptionAssembly.GetType("Encryption");
// But this returns null
```

I've got a bit of a headache with this one.  The class is public and I've definitely spelled it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to use the Object Browser in VS.

Comment: @HansPassant - Yep, I absolutely did. Detention for me tonight.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here

```
MessageBox.Show(t.FullName.ToString()); //FULLNAME
```

print out the `FullName` of the type and after use *that* `FullName` to get the type from the assembly.

Comment: Thanks.  This did it for me.  `FullName` tells me that it is "MyCompany.Library.Encryption".  Guess that's what happens when someone emails you a dll and says "here's the encryption assembly to use"!  Shame I can't accept all answers as others also pointed out that I needed the namespace.  I'll upvote them too.

Comment: Also - make sure class has a constructor ()

Answer (score 11):

You should specify a full namespace of a type, for example:

```
encryptionAssembly.GetType("My.Namespace.Encryption")
```

You can know it using `t.FullName`

Comment: +1.  Thanks.  I've got a feeling that will be handy again in future.

Answer (score 5):

try specifying the full name of the Encryption type (namespace.classname)

Comment: if you don't know it try looking for it with reflector

Comment: Thanks for that.  +1.  I've had to accept Tigran's answer though because he provided me the quickest way to determine `FullName`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know the the fully qualified name of my assembly at runtime, but I was able to get the type using only the class name from the assembly's ExportedTypes. For instance, to get an export type of "ClassName":

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
var types = assembly.ExportedTypes;
if(types != null)
{
    var type = types.Where(x => x.Name == "ClassName").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If there were multiple types with the identical name of "ClassName" this would only get the first one, but this is a safe solution for the dlls I'm loading.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the file/.cs file in my project was missing. I added the missing cs file and it worked like charm. I have a cs project named ProjectA. In that it code is looking for full class name ProjectA.ClassA. When I get this error I went to ProjectA and saw that ClassA.cs was missing due merge issue. I added/included ClassA.cs to ProjectA and it worked fine.